# Unable to return javascript confirm value in selenium webdriver using python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

in my code i am giving a javascript confirm to ask the user to click on oK or cancel. iF the user is clicking on OK then a certain set of code will be executed. i am using python and selenium webdriver but everytime i run the below code null value is being printed even after clicking OK or cancel

ss=driver.execute_script(" fg = confirm('Press a button!'); return fg; ")

print(ss)

time.sleep(5)

Comment: did you end up figuring out how to do it?